# Does OpenGL have any automatic texture interpolation?

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-atlas, glfw

An image of a minecraft grass block in gimp:

[image]

Loading from a texture atlas in OpenGL, gives a much blurrier image:

[image]

I know that the actual image in my glfw window is larger than it is in gimp.
(640x640 window, 64x64 image in gimp)
Is it possible that OpenGL is seeing this increase in size, and automatically interpolating the image, not keeping the sharpness between "pixels" on the block?

I am a beginner with OpenGL, so any suggestion on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: That blur is caused by bilinear filtering. Many graphics APIs enable bilinear filtering by default, because usually we don't want textures to look pixelated. I don't work with OpenGL directly, so I can't answer your question. However, if you do a web search for 'opengl disable bilinear', you'll get plenty of results (though it looks like most of them are more than 10 years old).

Comment: I'm a beginner with OpenGL myself, but you're probably setting the texture using `GL_LINEAR` instead of `GL_NEAREST`, which asks for interpolated instead of pixelated scaling. You can read [this wiki page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object#Filtering) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Texture filters

When creating a texture buffer you can set the pixel lookup method via the [glTexParameteri](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) call. See link for full details.

Example creates texture handle and set the pixel lookup filter used when reading pixels from the texture.

```
GLint lookup = GL_NEAREST; // gives pixelated render Does not interpolate
                           // or GL_LINEAR for smooth, the default setting
GLuint hdl;
glGenTextures(1, &hdl);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, hdl);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, lookup);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, lookup);
```